# I need to run a google sheet macro/script from the mobile app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote my first macro on google sheets hoping we can use it on mobile but later found out buttons don't work on the mobile platform.

Tried to implement the On Open (e) function but it doesn't trigger the macro

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (cell=='Sale!A21') {
  filldata();

  }
}
```

no response on edit

Comment: Well, what does `filldata` do, and how? If you add Stackdriver logging statements, do you observe them? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_stackdriver_logging

Comment: I was just doing this the other day as well. Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out a way to get scripts to run on command through the mobile app.

Comment: A1 notation doesn't return the sheet name